# How To Properly Update User Profile Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

What is the updated code to upload user profileImage, I got an error trying to update user profileImage.

How do I fix this error?

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIImage' with an argument list of
>   type '(@escaping () -> ())'

```
self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage{data; data!}
```

Comment: self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)

Comment: *Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.* https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

You are using { braces } whereas you need to use ( round brackets )

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code such as you are using {} instead of () .
So , the code will actually look like ...

```
self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

but since data is optional value , it can come as nil if not handled properly. This will lead to crash within your app . So use optional binding in such cases to check whether the data variables actually contain any values , like the code below.

```
    if let imageData = data{
        self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }else{
        self.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(named : "image_when_no_value_is_present")
}
```